# Can't resolve SIGABRT error - Times Table App with UITableView

Tags: swift

I am trying to build a times tables app with a slider and a UITableView, but it gives me the SIGABRT error. I have tried relinking every outlet and action as well as redoing it from scratch, but it still won't seem to work.

Since I cannot paste it in here correctly formatted, I put it on     pastebin.com

Debug code:   http://pastebin.com/cBaALXWq

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}
@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
    var timesTableIndex: Int = Int(sender.value)!
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(timesTableIndex*indexPath.row+1)
        return cell
    }
}

}
```

AppDelegate.swift; gives error in line 4

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

EDIT

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
var timesTableIndex: Int?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}
@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
    timesTableIndex = Int(sliderValue.value * 50)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
cell.textLabel.text = String(timesTableIndex*(1+indexPath.row))
return cell

}
```

Comment: are you getting same issue after update also ? did you created UITableview in Storyboard right? as i didn't find IBOutlet or programatically implementation of tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you've added `cellForRowAtIndex:` inside @IBAction method. What you need to do is to take it out from the method. In addition you need set the `timesTableIndex` variable as global so that it can be accessed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and call the `reloadData` method on `tableView` when you call `sliderMoved:` method.

```
var timesTableIndex: Int = 0 // Now global variable

@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
    timesTableIndex = Int(sender.value)!
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(timeTableIndex * indexPath.row + 1)"
     return cell
}
```

Also it seems that you are not using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method on your table view, so I've updated the code to use it. Not that you need to set the `Cell` reuse identifier in your storyboard.

Comment: alright, thanks for your answer. But now it says in the func tableView that it doesn't know what timesTableIndex is, even though I declared it globally.

Comment: Are you sure that it's globally defined in your controller class? Also, you should use this syntax:
`cell.textLabel.text = "\(timeTableIndex * indexPath.row + 1)"`

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I've put it into the original post. Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be your tableview code if you have created tableview in the storyboard

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var timesTableIndex: Int = 0

@IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: AnyObject) {
        timesTableIndex = Int(sliderValue.value * 50)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return timesTableIndex
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = String(1*(1+indexPath.row))
        return cell
}
```

If you have created your cell in the storyboard set the `CellReuseIdentifier` as 'cell' in the storyboard else you can register the class in the like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //tableView is IBOutlet instance of UITableview 
   tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "test")
}
```

Also please check you have set the tableview delegate/datasource in the storyboard tableview object

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem. I accidentally put the function which sets up the prototype cell outside the ViewController class, that explains everything. Thank you for helping me!